# How to force Ruby string to n characters

Tags: ruby, string, variables, string-length

How to force Ruby string variable output using `puts` to n characters so that if the variable is longer, it will be truncated, if shorter, it will be expanded by trailing or leading spaces?

Is there some standard method to do this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Ruby supports using format strings, like many other languages:

```
[11] (pry) main: 0> '%3.3s' % 'f'
=> "  f"
[12] (pry) main: 0> '%3.3s' % 'foo'
=> "foo"
[13] (pry) main: 0> '%3.3s' % 'foobar'
=> "foo"
```

If you want to pad on the right, use a `-` in the format string:

```
[14] (pry) main: 0> '%-3.3s' % 'f'
=> "f  "
[15] (pry) main: 0> '%-3.3s' % 'foo'
=> "foo"
[16] (pry) main: 0> '%-3.3s' % 'foobar'
=> "foo"
```

You could also use `printf` or `sprintf`, but I prefer the more generic [`%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25), which is like [`sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

From the `sprintf` docs:

```
  s   | Argument is a string to be substituted.  If the format
      | sequence contains a precision, at most that many characters
      | will be copied.
```

and:

```
-        | all           | Left-justify the result of this conversion.
```

---

> What if I want to pad not with spaces but with some other character?

The underlying Ruby code is written in C, and it's hard-coded to use `' '` as the pad character, so that's not possible directly, unless you want to modify the source, recompile your Ruby, and live with a one-off version of the language. Instead, you can do something like:

```
[17] (pry) main: 0> ('%-3.3s' % 'f').gsub(' ', '.')
=> "f.."
```

This gets a lot more complicated than a simple `gsub` though. Often it's better to adjust the string without using format strings if you need to supply special characters. Format strings are very powerful but they're not totally flexible.

Otherwise, I'd go with something like @steenslag's solution, which is the basis for rolling your own. You lose the ability to use format strings and have to rely on concatenating your strings or something similar to get columnar output, but it will also work.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that there should be some elegant way. What if I want to pad not with spaces but with some other character?

Comment: By themselves, `sprintf` AKA `format` AKA `%` don't support using alternate pad characters, but there are ways to work around it. You can use `tr` or `gsub` to replace pad characters, depending on whether you're outputting leading/trailing padding, or whether you have embedded spaces.

Comment: Yes, but the string itself shouldn't contain spaces.

Answer (score 55):

To make a string a fixed length **shorter**:

```
  str_var.slice(0..10) # starts at the first letter
```

To make a string a fixed length **longer**:

```
  str_var.ljust(10, ' ')
```

They could be combined into something like:

```
  (str_var.length > 10) ? str_var.slice(1..10) : str_var.ljust(10, ' ')
```

Where `str_var` is, of course, your string

Comment: But slice needs to start at zero no?  `str_var.slice(0..10)`

Answer (score 12):

```
class String
  def fix(size, padstr=' ')
    self[0...size].rjust(size, padstr) #or ljust
  end
end

p 'lettersletters'.fix(9) #=> "lettersle"
p 'letters'.fix(10, '.')  #=> "...letters"
```

Combines the `slice` method (the []) with `rjust`.

Answer (score 6):

For a pure Ruby one liner you might do this:

```
(str + ' ' * length)[0,length]
```

Which will yield:

```
str = "Hello"
length = 10
=> "Hello     "
```

or:

```
str = "Hello"
length = 2
=> "He"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a method to truncate strings I would check out [ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper#truncate](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/truncate)

From the examples:

```
truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away")

# => Once upon a time in a world...
```

Comment: I'm tooking forward to test this variant, but couldn't use TextHelper. How to do this the right way (which requires do I need)? I am using Ruby 1.9.3p194.